# Cannot find the management option in the Kaa Sandbox,updated kaa to 0.10.0

Tags: kaa

I currently have kaa 0.10.0,cannot find the sandbox management as in earlier version so that I may update the sandbox address.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have the Sandbox Management page as described in the [documentation](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Getting-started/#networking).
Try to clean up cache in your browser. Also investigate logs located in the /var/log/kaa/ directory for details. [Troubleshooting](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Administration-guide/Troubleshooting/) guide will be helpful.

Comment: I have cleared the entire cache but the management option isn't visible also to add I want to inform that Application Platform is 0.10.0 and Kaa Sandbox Frame 1.4.0

Comment: Provide all logs from Sandbox /var/log/kaa/ directory for detailed investigation.

Comment: Here is the link ,I have archived all https://www.dropbox.com/s/n2gbhq4dr1ay5ep/kaa_logs.rar?dl=0

Comment: Kindly guide me with the logs posted to help analyze the cause of the issue

Comment: Thank you for provided information, I have created an issue http://jira.kaaproject.org/browse/KSF-109 and we will resolve it.

Comment: Thanks for information,so should I keep going with it without any issue?Also in previous you mentioned  the option was coming was it same version or other?

Comment: I mentioned earlier about Sandbox for Kaa 0.10.0 version. You can change a host/IP using Sandbox VM terminal as described in the networking section of Getting started guide http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Getting-started/ .

Comment: Kindly do guide me as I have updated using command how to verify is kaa using the ip I have stored?

Comment: You can check transport_public_interface property in kaa-node.properties file as described in network interface http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Administration-guide/System-installation/Single-node-installation/#network-interface configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance yes it shows the needed ip I had entered